# Export multiple JAR from Multiple Packages in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I currently have one project that currently contains multiple packages. **These packages make up an Eclipse Plug-in (I felt this was important enough to make bold)**.

What I wish to do is export, for example: "package1" as "package1.jar" and "package2" as "package2.jar".

I should mention that I can export "package1" successfully using the "Eclipse Product Export Wizard", but it only makes "package1.jar". How can I specify a second package in here to export as a separate jar?

Thanks

PS. I can right click on the package and hit "Export - Java - Runnable Jar File" which creates a perfectly good working version of "package2", but I wish this to be part of the export / build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Exporting, in one of the screen, it will ask you to select the files/packages to export.
Exactly in the screen where it says **Select Resource to Export**

Repeat the export process for every package by selecting and deselecting appropriate package

For Example

If you want to export package3 as package3.jar, deselect all other packages.

You can even select individual files

Comment: Thank-you for your swift response. However, I wish to automate this as part of my Eclipse Product Export, and in that screen, there is no resource selection. My product / plugin has to be compiled for multiple platforms.

Comment: May i know why you want to use Runnable Jar. You want to make them executable? I mean stand alone.

Comment: The first package is fine running as an Eclipse plugin. The second package needs to be a stand-alone Jar application.

Comment: Then dont select Runnable Jar. Select Simple Jar.
So you will have the option to select the package.
In the last screen, where you will give finish, select the "Main Class". Doing this, makes the jar executable.

Comment: Thats fine and works great, but it doesn't create this JAR again when I run "Eclipse Export Product Wizard" to generate the different platform versions of my plug-in. It only creates "package1" again.

Comment: Then you have to move all package to separate project and add to reference. So that you will have one stand alone and other support jars

Answer (score 0):

If you want your build automated, you better use a tool like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).

There is also a maven plugin for Eclipse called [m2eclipse](http://www.sonatype.org/m2eclipse), that can make your life much easier.